# Que libreria usar en C para buscar un regex

Tags: c, regex

estoy usando un regex en para hacer coincidir todos los numeros que esten entre 41 y 45 , ya tengo la expresion regular hecha pero no se que libreria de C utilizar para buscarlo

li que quiero es hacer tipo

```
int numero = 41
if(4[1-5] == numero)
{
printf("El numero se encuentra entre 41 y 45");
}
```

estuve leyendo y al parecer es sys/types.h
pero tiene muchas funciones y no se cual utilizar para este caso ya que tiene
re_comp, re_exec, regcomp, regerror, regex, regexec, regfree

Comment: Que sepa, regex sirve para manipular strings, no enteros. Lo que quieres hacer seria un if (numero>=45 || numero<=41). Si realmente quieres usar regex en strings, hay la libreria regex.h, y puedes encontrar el manual aqui: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html

Comment: C es un lenguaje de programación. Cuenta con una fase de preprocesado pero no específicamente de regex. Puedes escribir tu propio lenguaje de programación que tenga soporte para notación regex o pensar en otra cosa como te sugirió Arnau.

Comment: La biblioteca estándar de C no tiene funciones para analizar *regex*. Necesitas crear una biblioteca desde 0 o utilizar bibliotecas de terceros como: [wregex](https://github.com/wernsey/wregex), [tiny-regex](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-regex-c).